# What does exchange symmetry of arguments imply for the symmetry group of a function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $s_1,s_2 \in M$ where $M$ is a discrete and finite set. Consider a function $H(s_1,s_2): M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $S_N\subset M$ and $S_N$ is the permutation group of $N$ objects. It is given that $H(s_1,s_2)=H(s_2,s_1)$ and that $H(s_1,s_2)$ has group $G$ (also discrete and finite) as its largest symmetry group. $g\in G$ acts on $s\in M$ via conjugation, ie, $s\mapsto gsg^{-1}$. We also know that $S_N \times S_N \subset G$. In fact, when restricted to $S_N$, $H(s_1,s_2)$ has $S_N \times S_N$ as its largest symmetry group.

From this information alone, can anyone say anything about the contents/structure of $G$ and/or the functional form of the function $H$? I was thinking along the lines that the exchange symmetry $(s_1\leftrightarrow s_2)$ of the function must put constraints on $G$. However, I am not sure what exactly.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question?